# Labels in Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have started new with the sonata admin bundle. its very handy and easy to setup and use , but i can't seem to get the translation fixed for the default labels

e.g link_add, link_list are coming instead of proper english labels.

```
#SonataAdmin
    sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

sonata_admin:
    title:      Sonata Project
    title_logo: /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig

    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }
```

This is my config file and these are the basic default settings provided by the documentation. what am i missing here to enable labels for the default view params ? can anybody help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

for translate menu and forms override file: `SonataAdminBundle.[your_language].xliff`(with content from: `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Sonata/AdminBundle/Resources/translations/SonataAdminBundle.[your_language].xliff`), put file in:

```
app/Resource/SonataAdminBundle/translations/
```

full path:

```
app/Resource/SonataAdminBundle/translations/SonataAdminBundle.[your_language].xliff
```

If you want to translate your labels for field, you must create translate file in your bundle, for example:

```
src/YourAlias/YourNameOfBundle/Resources/translations/YourAliasYourNameOfBundle.[your_language].xliff
```

if your `Admin` class is in

```
src/YourAlias/YourNameOfBundle/Admin/YourClassAdmin.php
```

`Sonata` use `FOSUserBundle` and if you want change translation for users module, you must ovverride file: `FOSUserBundle.[your_language].yml` in:

```
app/Resource/FOSUSerBundle/translations/FOSUserBundle.[your_language].yml
```

and analogously for `SonataUserBundle`

I use that configuration and everything works!

Comment: but how to enable the default translation from the translation files sonata admin bundle already has with it . the labels generated by sonata bundle are not working . they are showing the default twig parameters. any suggestions about that ?

Comment: in `config.yml`: `framework: # ... translator:      { fallback: %locale% }` and `paramaters: locale: [your_laguage]` in `parameters.yml`.

Comment: Hello @mkjasinski, I override app/Resource/SonataAdminBundle/translations/SonataAdminBundle.es.xliff and new translation, about breadcrumb. This is my code, but no working: `<trans-unit id="breadcrumb.link_categorias_list">
                <source>breadcrumb.link_categorias_list</source>
                <target>Listado Categorias</target>
            </trans-unit>` Can you please help me?

Comment: thanks @mkjasinski , I did, but I still appears Categories List, when should appear "Listado Categorias"

Comment: Please read this http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/translation.html.

Comment: It didn't resolv my issue until I replace xliff file extension by xlf as describe in this page : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-resource-locations (Sorry, I'm not fluent in English)

Comment: Thanks this helped.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on @mkjasinski's comment above, the Symfony Translation component expects to find a `_locale` property on the request. If this is missing, or no translation can be found for the specified locale, it uses a fallback value. However this fallback value is also blank by default hence seeing the translation labels instead of text.

To fix this, set the [default translation locale](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#setting-a-default-locale) by adding the following to `config.yml`:

```
framework:
  #...
  translator:
    fallback: %locale%
```