# How to properly translate strings in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am trying to translate some Sonata Admin - list page - strings using `.xliff` file inside my bundle. Those strings belongs to my bundle and not to Sonata so this are the steps I have follow:

- Create a `.xliff` file under: `src/Clanmovil/PlatformBundle/Resources/translations/PlatformBundle.es.xliff` as follow:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
      <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="PlatformBundle.en.xliff" >
          <body>
              <trans-unit id="name">
                  <source>name</source>
                  <target>Nombre</target>
              </trans-unit>
              <trans-unit id="description">
                  <source>description</source>
                  <target>Descripción</target>
              </trans-unit>
              <trans-unit id="active">
                  <source>active</source>
                  <target>Activo?</target>
              </trans-unit>
          </body>
      </file>
  </xliff>
  ```
- Setup `label` property under `src/Clanmovil/PlatformBundle/Controller/Admin/CategoryAdmin.php` as follow:

  ```
  class CategoryAdmin extends Admin
  {
      ...

      // Fields to be shown on lists
      protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
      {
          $listMapper
              ->add('name', null, array(
                  'label' => 'name'
              ))
              ->add('active', null, array(
                  'label' => 'active'
              ));
          ...
      }

      ...
  }
  ```
- Setup `app/config/config.yml` as follow:

  ```
  parameters:
      locale: es

  framework:
      #esi:             ~
      translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
      default_locale:  "%locale%"
      ....
  ```

And is not working I am still seeing `name` and `active` strings on list page and I don't know what I am missing. I have read several posts as [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/_eQIffgcn4U), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685256/how-to-translate-labels-in-sonata-admin-bundle) and many more. Can any give me some advice?

---

Since the previous issue was fixed with the answer provided but this is almost the same I decide to edit the OP than create a new one so here we go. Take a look to the following setup for SonataAdmin:

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            configuration:
                icon: <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa fa-folder"></i>
                label: configuration
                items:
                    - sonata.admin.category
                    - sonata.admin.command
                    - sonata.admin.alias
```

And this is the definition of those services at `Clanmovil/PlatformBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.alias:
        class: Clanmovil\PlatformBundle\Controller\Admin\AliasAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Configuration", label: "alias" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Clanmovil\PlatformBundle\Entity\Alias
            - ~
    sonata.admin.category:
        class: Clanmovil\PlatformBundle\Controller\Admin\CategoryAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Configuration", label: "category" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Clanmovil\PlatformBundle\Entity\Category
            - ~
    sonata.admin.command:
        class: Clanmovil\PlatformBundle\Controller\Admin\CommandAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Configuration", label: "command" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Clanmovil\PlatformBundle\Entity\Command
            - ~
```

But strings `configuration`, `command` and `category` (for now) aren't translated, see pic below:

[image]

Why? Those translations are on the same file as the `alias` one. What could be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify translation domain explicitly, if you create your translations files different than `messages`. `messages` is the default translation domain. You have two options, rename your `PlatformBundle.es.xliff` to `messages.es.xliff` or specify tranlation domain. example:

In form types:

```
...
$builder->add('name', 'text', ['translation_domain' => 'PlatformBundle']);
...
```

in twig trmplates:

```
{{ 'name'|trans({}, 'PlatformBundle') }}
```

I don't know what is the `ListMapper` class, but there should be support (I guess) for translation domains also.

Comment: can you take a look to the OP again under the horizontal rule? I have made an edit because is not working for me

Comment: @ReynierPM Did you read this [doc page](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/translation.html)?

Comment: yes I did but what I miss here? Do I need to setup something else? I am not clear at all can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @ReynierPM I'm at work now. I can look at your problems later, at home.

Comment: no rush, just take a look when you can do it and thanks for your help