# Customize Download in the list view Sonata Admin

Tags: php, csv, sonata-admin, sonata, exporter

I want to remove csv, xml and json formats from Download. Where can i customize this page?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do right now is override the `getExportFormats` method of your admin, so that it returns the list of formats that you really want.

In the future, you will be able to configure that globally thanks to [this contribution I made](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter/commit/041b89895400e612c63f3243f49a2967c6bd80e1).

If you also want to change the button to a link, you need to override the list template, and customize the `table_footer` block (the template to override is `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_list.html.twig`), so just copy/paste and adapt the `table_footer` block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just found about it and it worked. If you can tell me about how to disappear this download button, it would be great :)

Comment: Thank you so much @greg0ire :)

Comment: I want to. But i don't have enough reputation to upvote. So sorry :(

Comment: i just added and new download format (PDF). But it displays export_format_pdf. How to display it PDF ?

Comment: Translate it I guess?

Comment: May be sort of. But not really. When i click on Download it shows me dropdown and there are {CSV, XSL, .., export_format_pdf}
I want to display it like {CSV, XSL, ..., PDF}

Comment: Don't know how to translate it :(

Comment: Does `export_format_pdf` appear under "Missing translations", in the profiler?

Comment: Yes. It appears under "Missing translations"

Comment: Great. What is the catalog for this missing translation?

Comment: It says SonataAdminBundle

Comment: Thank you @greg0ire. I just figured out.
I created translation file in "app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/translations" directory and translated neccessary words.
More info at: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476707/labels-in-sonata-admin-bundle)